# How to track an unmodified file on a specific revision in git?

Tags: git

Say I have a repo with revisions `A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L-M`. A file `foo.txt` is recorded modified (or created) in `B`, `G`, `J`. I want to additionally bind revision `C` and `E` to the history of foo.txt so that I get `B-C-E-G-J` with a simple command regarding `foo.txt` such as `git log -- foo.txt`. Is there a way to achieve that?

If this is impossible, is there a good alternative?

(More details follow)

The reason is that A~M are snapshots of an old project and were imported to the git repo later on. Something happened during the course and the actual state of foo.txt on snapshot C and E were missing althogh both actually have foo.txt modified. However the change messages (commit messages) of C and E had something to do with the changing course of foo.txt and should be included in the history list of foo.txt. Therefore I want to receive the commit messages of them when `git log -- foo.txt`, as if `git add -- foo.txt` had been run and taken effect on revision C and E.

Comment: The only way I see is to modify history and actually edit the file in question (add a line, add whitespace, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

When you run `git log -- foo.txt`, you are getting only the commits that have changes to that file.  So the reason that you are only getting commits A-D instead of the whole tree is that foo.txt wasn't changed in B & C.

Git stores the changes of the system in each commit.  In commits B & C, there were no changes to foo.txt.  So the commit won't have any modifications to that file.  It doesn't matter if some ran `git add foo.txt`, there are no changes to the file so there is nothing to add or commit.

Adding the file name allows you to track the changes in the file so that you can see how it changed during the course of a project.

If you want to get all the commits between A & D, you want to run `git log A..D`.  You can add the `--name-only` option to see the files that were changed in each commit or use the `-p` option to see all changes made in that commit.

Comment: I must haven't explained my problem well enough in the original version of question so I edited afterward. Thank you for answering but I think what I need is a different answer, though.